# Error when trying to create an iot component in AWS greengrass version 2 using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-iot-greengrass

I recently did a configuration where I created a component in using the aws console for greengrass from a recipe and another where I imported the config from a lambda file. They both work well when I do it using the aws console. However, I want to be able to produce this same configuration using cloudformation. I have read the documentation here [component version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-greengrassv2-componentversion.html) and it says I can be able to add a recipe file inline or send it a lambda function using the `LambdaFunctionRecipeSource`. However all my attempt fail with the error

```
Resource handler returned message: "User: arn:aws:iam::accountIDHere:user/harisu is not 
authorized to perform: null (Service: GreengrassV2, Status Code: 403, Request ID: f517f1ff-a387-
4380-8a47-bd6d41fd628e, Extended Request ID: null)" 
(RequestToken: d6f8042d-687e-0afa-e75d-d80f27a7f177, HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied)
```

I have however granted administrator access to the user `harisu` and I ensured he has the full access to the greengrass service.
My example cfn file is

```
  TestComponentVersion:
    Type: AWS::GreengrassV2::ComponentVersion
    Properties: 
      InlineRecipe: "---
        RecipeFormatVersion: '2020-01-25'
        ComponentName: com.example.HelloWorld
        ComponentVersion: 1.0.0
        ComponentDescription: My first AWS IoT Greengrass component.
        ComponentPublisher: Amazon
        ComponentConfiguration:
          DefaultConfiguration:
            Message: world
        Manifests:
        - Name: Linux
          Platform:
            os: linux
          Lifecycle:
            Run: |
              python3 {artifacts:path}/hello_world.py '{configuration:/Message}'
          Artifacts:
           - URI: s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/artifacts/com.example.HelloWorld/1.0.0/hello_world.py
     "
```

I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this when troubleshooting, refer to https://greengrassv2.workshop.aws/en/chapter4_createfirstcomp/30_step3.html. It states that this is typically caused by the recipe definition not being valid json or yaml. In my case this was true, I had a yaml syntax error. I don't immediately see if that is the case here or where your error is.